# Call action within another graph, how to pass the adapter

Tags: acumatica

My goal is, from a given screen : 
- Add lines to the Adjustments tab of the payment & application graph
- Release

I tried to do this :

```
override public void createLettering(List<ARRegister> lines)
        {
            string refNbr = "";
            foreach (ARRegister line in lines)
            {
                if (line.DocType == "PMT") refNbr = line.RefNbr;
            }

            // Get the paymententry graph, and add the invoice
            ARPaymentEntry graphPmt = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARPaymentEntry>();
            ARPayment pmt = PXSelect<ARPayment, Where<ARPayment.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARPayment.refNbr>>,
                                And<ARPayment.docType, Equal<Required<ARPayment.docType>>>>>
                                    .Select(this,refNbr, "PMT");
            graphPmt.Document.Current = pmt;
            if (pmt == null) throw new PXException(Constantes.errNotFound);
            //pmt.CuryOrigDocAmt = 0m;
            //graphPmt.Document.Update(pmt);
            ARAdjust adj = new ARAdjust();
            foreach(ARRegister line in lines)
            {
                if (line.DocType == "INV")
                {
                    adj = new ARAdjust();
                    adj.AdjdDocType = line.DocType;
                    adj.AdjdRefNbr = line.RefNbr;
                    graphPmt.Adjustments.Insert(adj);

                }
            }
            PXAdapter adapter = new PXAdapter(new PXView(graphPmt,true, graphPmt.Document.View.BqlSelect));
            graphPmt.Persist();
            graphPmt.Release(adapter);
        }
```

My problem is I think my adapter gets every single ARPayment in it and thus tries to release them all. (The output of this function is : long processing time and then tells me 'PaymentMethod can't be null', but the paymentMethod of my graphPmt.Document is not null when I check in debug).

so How do I pass a correct PXAdapter to the Release(PXAdapter adapter) method of the PaymentEntry graph, from another custom graph of mine ?

Comment: This line saved my life.  PXAdapter adapter = new PXAdapter(new PXView(graphPmt,true, graphPmt.Document.View.BqlSelect));  Thank you.  I was able to adapt it to my need.  I was not able to figure out how to get an adapter from a graph!  THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you should be able to call the action such as...

```
graphPmt.release.Press();
```

I have not tested this but I recall doing something like this for other actions in the past.